# How to set the ValueConversion attribut for a IMultiValueConverter

Tags: wpf, imultivalueconverter

I changed my converter from IValueConverter to IMultiValueConverter :
Previously I converted int to string :

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(string))]
```

But now I convert an int and a double to a string.

How should I specify my ValueConversion attribut now ? I have two input and one output now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I dont think you can use `ValueConversionAttribute` with an implementation of `IMultiValueConverter`

I think `ValueConversionAttribute` is primarily used for design-time support and `MultiBindings` dont seem to make much sense in this context

Answer (score 6):

I've never seen `ValueConversionAttribute` applied to `IMultiValueConverter` implementing class. And there is no appropriate attribute for this kind of converter in `System.Windows.Data` namespace. You can safely omit the attribute at all.